# Angle at the suspension point of a chain

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

If you have a chain suspended between two points at an equal height, the curve it forms should be a catenary:

$$
y = a\cosh\frac{x}{a}
$$

The chain I'm interested in is suspended between two points at the same height, with $2x_s$ meters being the distance between them. I also know that the middle of the chain hangs $s$ meters below the suspension points.

What I wish to know is at what angle does the chain connect to the suspension points? By differentiating the catenary, I was able to get this as the equation of the angle:

$$
\alpha = \arctan\left(\sinh \frac{x_s}{a}\right)
$$

The issue is, I don't know how to calculate $a$ given the information I have. I got to this equation by subtracting suspension points and the lowest point:

$$
a\cosh \frac{x_s}{a} - a - s = 0
$$

Does this have a sane analytical solution or do I have to calculate it numerically?

Comment: Always you bave an equation with any function of $x\exp{x}$ or sth. similar like $x+\exp{x}$ or with any other function that is not a polynomial (there are special cases) you must calculate the root $x$ numerically. Since you have $a\cosh{(x_s/a)}$ you must obtain $a$ numerically.

Comment: @HBR If that were an answer, I'd have accepted it. Simple and with useful remarks for similar future issues.

Comment: Using the approximation $y=\frac{1}{2a}x^2+a$ in substitution to your catenary function, you get $a=\frac{x_s^2}{2s}$.

Comment: @RicardoCruz This seems like a pretty accurate approximation for the numbers I'm entering. I see almost no difference compared to numeric solutions. Thanks!